# Amazon Lex Model Building Service: how to build and publish a bot by SDK?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I'm creating a Amazon Lex deployment script using Javascript.
After creating multiple slots and intents, what is the correct way of creating a new bot, building it and publishing it using the SDK?

I succeed to do so manually through the console, but fail to do so by the Javascript SDK.

After reading the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/LexModelBuildingService.html), I created successfully new slot types, new intents and new intent versions. Anyway, I failed to get a new bot alias up and published using the method `putBotAlias()`.

After inspecting the console, and trying to publish the just created bot manually, I got the error:

> Resource 'MyBotName' should refer to immutable versions to create new version

After building it manually via the console, I succeeded to publish it also manually.

I expect `putBotAlias()` to build and publish the bot, but in actuality, an alias is created but the bot is seemed not built and not published.

Comment: related: an issue on the AWS SDK for Go, see [this comment](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/2524#issuecomment-476911769), and [that one](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/2524#issuecomment-477383090).